# EACCESS error while using npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm making a node script to deploy meteor app to my server;
Once uploaded the package and unzipped, I get EACCESS error while using npm;

since on the server there is nvm installed as root, I run:

```
sudo /root/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm install
```

in the programs/server;

the output is:

```
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
/
> fibers@1.0.1 install /var/www/igor/paesidisandalmazzo.it/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

child_process.js:1120
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
          ^
Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:745:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1120:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:971:9)
    at build (/var/www/igor/paesidisandalmazzo.it/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build.js:52:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/igor/paesidisandalmazzo.it/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build.js:44:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/root/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.11.12
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.1 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.1 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/igor/paesidisandalmazzo.it/programs/server/npm-debug.log
```

can someone help to figure this out?

Comment: did you try it with sudo?

Comment: as you can see above, the command used is:  sudo /root/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm install

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that fibers is installed with another version of node, hence v0.11.12 - since the log is showing it in the middle.

Try `sudo npm uninstall fibers` maybe `sudo npm uninstall fibers -g` and then `npm install fibers` to compile again fibers in your wanted node environment.

I have had some similar problems when I have packaged the meteor app. When you'd do that, Meteor outputs a Readme.md explicitly telling you to reinstall one or two dependencies.